# Oracle 21c: How to performantly clone schema and rows to the same server under a different DB name?

Tags: oracle

I am having difficulties understanding how to go about doing something like this:

- Say I have an Oracle database named `EXAMPLE`, with tables `USERS` and `FOOBAR`
- I want to clone the `EXAMPLE` database into `NEW_DB`, preserving the schema and data

  - So I wind up with `NEW_DB`.`USERS` and `NEW_DB`.`FOOBAR`

It seems like maybe `expdb` and `impdb` could be used for this, but there are few resources/tutorials available online that show their use.

With MySQL for example, this can be done using `mysqldump` and piping that into `mysql` like:

- `mysqldump <connection params for DB1> | mysql <connection params for DB2>`

What might be an equivalent set of commands for Oracle, if anyone happens to know?

Comment: expdp and impdp are indeed the proper tools. There are plenty of resources about datapump available on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer, in case anyone comes across this in the future.

Here we create a new db, `$cloneName` which winds up containing the contents of the `chinook` schema.

The trick is to use `schema` and `remap_schema` it seems, as my coworker discovered:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'CREATE USER "$cloneName" IDENTIFIED BY p4ssw0rd DEFAULT TABLESPACE users TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp QUOTA 10M ON users;' | sqlplus sys/p4ssw0rd@localhost:1535 as sysdba

echo 'GRANT connect TO "$cloneName";' | sqlplus sys/p4ssw0rd@localhost:1535 as sysdba
echo 'GRANT resource TO "$cloneName";' | sqlplus sys/p4ssw0rd@localhost:1535 as sysdba
echo 'GRANT create session TO "$cloneName";' | sqlplus sys/p4ssw0rd@localhost:1535 as sysdba
echo 'GRANT create table TO "$cloneName";' | sqlplus sys/p4ssw0rd@localhost:1535 as sysdba
echo 'GRANT create view TO "$cloneName";' | sqlplus sys/p4ssw0rd@localhost:1535 as sysdba
echo 'GRANT read, write on directory chinook TO "$cloneName";' | sqlplus sys/p4ssw0rd@localhost:1535 as sysdba

expdp \'chinook/p4ssw0rd@localhost:1535\' schemas=chinook directory=chinook dumpfile=chinook.dmp exclude=statistics
impdp \'\"$cloneName\"/p4ssw0rd@localhost:1535\' remap_schema=chinook:\"$cloneName\" directory=chinook dumpfile=chinook.dmp transform=disable_archive_logging:y
```